# Google OAuth consent screen does not show new requested sensitive scopes

Tags: oauth, screen, scopes

I have requested Google to approve sensitive scopes. Until now the application was accessing the basic name and email data. However, the new requested scopes do not show up on the consent screen. Google requires me to share a video with the new OAuth consent screen but I don't have a way to show the new scopes until they update it. What am I doing wrong? I have looked up other questions and resources and did not find any question specific to this problem related to the sensitive scopes. [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I'm requesting the correct scopes and even have `&prompt=consent` in the url but the page never shows requested scopes

Answer (score 6):

The scopes that appear on the consent screen are sent by your code in the authorization setup.   Adding them to google developer console just tells google you will be using these.  Its your code that needs to request them.

If your not seeing them you haven't added the scopes to the authorization request in your code.